# Top Dead Centre

Tags: engine, toyota

I replaced a cylinder head gasket on my 1993 Holden Apollo (Same engine as the toyota camry 5S-FE). However when I went to get TDC I think I may have forgotten to put the car in Neutral. Could this have caused any damage to the engine? The car won't start now that it's all back together and I fear something has gone wrong.

Comment: Define no start. Does it crank but won't run, does it not crank at all?

Answer (score 6):

Four stroke engines get to TDC twice during a cycle - if you timed the engine off the wrong one (TDC on exhaust cycle), the engine will not fire as the timing will be out by 180°.

Answer (score 5):

Leaving the car in gear should not have had any effect, when you turned the engine it would have simply turned the wheels.

I suspect the distributor may be 180 degrees out but I need more information from you about the condition.